# Trying to use Head from next/head in reactjs site

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have used Head from next/head in my reactjs app. However, it didn't work and neither it gave me any error.

I just called

```
Import Head from 'next/head'
<Head> 
<title>{dynamicValue}</title></Head>
```

But it's not working.

I need to do any special settings to use Head from Next ????

Comment: Is your site built with next.js?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @BryanDowning no, it's built using npx create-react-app. Actually, I have used react helmet to include meta tags and I need to render the <head> on the server-side as twitter and fb bots do not run js.

 Due to some complications, I am not able to run the react helmet on the server-side. I read some of the blogs in which coders used Head from Next.js quite easily merely by adding Import Head from 'next/head'. Do you think I am missing something??? Thanks

Comment: @DvidSilva I need to render meta tags on the Server-side. Therefore, I am trying to use the Head from Next.js. I installed the package and imported the file but it did not work either it has given any error...

Comment: You basically need to use next.js if you want to use next/head (like, `npx create-next-app`). Check out https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started